# vue sass-loader и немного бреда

Tags: vue.js

Создал новый проект с помощью vue-cli, выбрал там опцию добавить препроцессоры, добавил файл vue.config.js, в общем сделал абсолютно все то же самое, что и в предыдущем проекте где все нормально работало. Но в этом проекте какая то загадочная магия происходит, если в компоненте App.vue например написать вот такое:

```
<style lang="scss">
  //
</style>
```

то из файла main.scss стили применяются, но если убрать тег style или просто удалить из него кавычки, то стили работать не будут

файл vue.config.js выглядит так

```
const path = require('path');
    module.exports = {
      pluginOptions: {
        i18n: {
          locale: 'en',
          fallbackLocale: 'en',
          localeDir: 'locales',
          enableInSFC: true
        }
      },
      css: {
        loaderOptions: {
          sass: {
            sassOptions: {
              includePaths: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
              ],
            },
            prependData: `@import "./src/assets/styles/main.scss";`
          },
        },
      },
      assetsDir: '@/assets/',
    }
```

в файле main.scss я импортирую переменные, если в App.js написать

```
 <style lang="scss">
      #app {
         background-color: $color;
     }
 </style>
```

то опять таки стили применяться, а это значит что путь правильный, но почему если убрать тег style или удалить из него все содержимое и оставить пустым, то он игнорирует все стили которые там написаны?

единственная разница между тем проектом и этим состоит только в том, что я обновил node.js и всё.
Почему в прошлом проекте после всех проделанных действий я пишу стили в файле main.scss и это работает, то в этом только после каких то странных танцев с бубном и тегом style.

Comment: Что значит убрать тег стайл? И как он еще должен реагировать на стили без этого тега? Сформулируйте ваш вопрос по другому, непонятно о какой проблеме вы говорите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам нужен глобальный стиль, тогда Вам потребуется импорт стилей в самом `App.vue`:

```js
<template>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name : "TestComponent"
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import '@/styles/_global';
</style>
```

Если Вам же нужны изолированные стили для каждого компонента, то соответственно, такие импорты нужно делать отдельно в каждом компоненте.